# First time the sail ship technology took off

Tags: age-of-sail

At what point in history did the sail ship technology take off for the first time?
And by that I mean sail ships that significantly eased trade across water and which got produced in significant quantities over significant times.

There were Triremes back in classical times but the image is they were partially powered by slaves rowing down below indicating they weren't that advanced at the time. You can never row your way across large distances cheaply.

Then sailships were continuously becoming better in the 9th century in northern Europe, but I'm not sure how much further back their development goes and what was going on elsewhere.

I find this question important because the ability to send things cheaply from A to B (be it people, ideas or general trade) is a fundamental building block of civilization. Which makes the sail ship a very fundamental technology in history.

Comment: "never row your way across vast distances cheaply"  - so you're only talking about intercontinental trade flows? I'm growing doubtful that I understand the question.  I think that Egypt shipped large quantities of grain and goods down the Nile by sailing ship.  I think the Triremes to which you refere are primarily warships, and crewed by free men.

Comment: Not intercontinental necessarily but distances of 10km+. If the triremes were just warships then that leaves the state of sailships as unknown. About the Nile ships, its quite important what kind of vessels those were and if they were used in significant quantities to significantly ease trade.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, Hermann. Regarding the Nile, there is a particularity worth noting: the Nile stream carries ships downstream. Conversely, the dominating winds blow from North to South and thus carry the ships upstream. This is shown on many antic reliefs on site and in museums (in Mastabas for instance).  So, on their way to lower Egypt, sailors would simply use the stream and would instead use the force of the wind on their way back to upper Egypt. This can be interpreted as an indication that sail ships were probably used pretty early in ancient Egypt. Later models have been found as well.

Comment: @AlainPannetier, I suggest that you've just answered OP's question.  (I had a dim memory of that, but you've got the details I lacked). That is evidence that sailing ships were used to move goods 10's of kilometers.

Comment: But I mean that's just a single river and a single project. I'm wondering of where trade has become routine using sails. Guess I should update my question.

Comment: "When did sail ships take off" As I read that, I saw in my head, two ships flying through the air.

Comment: An accurate answer probably depends on the exact meaning of "take off". International commerce was important since ancient times, but probably the first people whose state revolved around maritime commerce were the Minoans and Phoenicians.

Comment: Is it known what kind of sailships they had and how effective they were?

Comment: I am gathering material to see if I can give a satisfactory answer...

Comment: I agree with @astabada that the term take-off can be multi-interpretable. What is taking off? When the Portuguese and Spanish started exploring the worlds and globalization started? Or does it mean that a prehistoric society was able to stretch it's range further than was humanly possible at that moment? obviously I would choose the latter, because it is a lot easier to define.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real answer to your question is when navigation became effective. The Greeks and Romans had not invented the compass and as such were not known to navigate outside the sight of land. Grain shipments from what is now Tunisia and Libya would travel eastwards to Egypt and north to Turkey and then westwards towards Italy. Someone with a compass would just head north - cutting a significant amount of time off the voyage.

Non-europeans were good navigators, and had sailing vessels, but due to lack of written records, tend to get left out of history books. [Recent DNA evidence](http://www.nature.com/news/dna-shows-how-the-sweet-potato-crossed-the-sea-1.12257) shows that Polynesians obtained sweet potatoes from South America and distributed them to other Polynesian islands centuries before Europeans reached South America.

Finally, triremes were warships and were not used for cargo carrying.

Answer (score 2):

Archeologists have found the first "picture" of a sailing vessel in a prehistoric period of Mesopotamia, called the [Ubaid period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubaid_period) (ca. 6500 to 3800 BC). Somewhere to be carbon dated between 5500 and 5000 BC.

An actual image of this picture as well as more information can be seen in [Antique: "Boat remains and maritime trade in the Persian Gulf during the sixth and fifth millennia BC", Robert Carter](http://www.academia.edu/173149/Boat_remains_and_maritime_trade_in_the_Persian_Gulf_during_the_sixth_and_fifth_millennia_BC).

> Boat-related ﬁnds consist of a ceramic model of a reed-bundle boat
>   (Figure 3); a painteddisc depicting a sailing boat ([Figure 4](http://htmlimg4.scribdassets.com/7j7hcbc0zk8xxcq/images/5-dcf602d657.jpg)) and over
>   50 pieces of bituminous amalgam, mostly  with reed-impressions and/or
>   barnacle encrustations, which are interpreted as fragments of the
>   waterproof coating of sea-going reed-bundle boats (Figure 5)